# github protected branch exemption

Tags: git, github

I would like to protect the master branch on my GitHub repos, as it is good practice and my team has had a few incidents with unintended pushes to master.

However, as a part of my required workflow I need to publish a changelog to the repo when promoting a new version of the library that the repo represents.

Conceptually, this is not code that should be reviewed, so the scripts I use push the changelog updates directly to master (not great, I know, but better than having to make PRs to review a changelog).

So, with the background in place, my question is this:

*Is there any way to enable a protected master branch without blocking the update script?*

So far, I have considered the following but was unable to find a way to implement them / considered them too hacky to be a good idea:

- Exclude a file from the protected status of a branch (ie, allow commits which only edit the changelog to be pushed directly to master)
- Have the script temporarily disable the protection on the branch
- Make a PR and automatically merge it
- Add jenkins to the list of users allowed to push to master, then have Jenkins somehow generate the changelog and commit it to the master on a PR merge

If anyone has any better ideas for how to achieve this (or knows of a way to effectively implement one of the above), please chime in!

Answer (score -1):

GitHub has a variety of options that can be used to configure this. By default, administrators are exempt from this restriction. In addition, if your repositories are part of an organization (and possibly for individuals with collaborators), you can specify additional people or groups to be exempted from the requirement.

You can open the protected branches option and start to add a branch to see all the options, but skip saving if you decide you just want to look and don't want to change anything yet.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question. I want all of my team members (myself included) to be able to push changelog updates but not directly to master otherwise.